# Make text loaded from plist to scroll

Tags: xcode, load, scroll, plist

I am new to iOS and need to fix something.

I have a view with a bunch of labels that are replaced with the info I have in a plist file, everything works fine and all the text appears as it should in my view.

The only problem I have is with the string I use for description, its a long text and I need that to be scrollable in my view. That way I can have 2 paragraphs in the string and it will load in the box I need it to.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UILabels don't have scrollbars built in.

Use a [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/) instead.

If you'd like to see what they look like before you attempt to modify your own code, why not download [Apple's "UICatalog" sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) (which is a whole project -- and code -- showing many views available within the UIKit framework).

Comment: Thanks Michael.
If I create an IBOutlet for it just as I have all the labels, its not working.

So I assume I can't just create it, let it know what string to read and thats it ?